# Deslizar un input range desde un punto que no sea el medio

Tags: html, html5, css

¿Cómo puedo hacer que un input range tenga el elemento que se desliza más ancho? Quiero conseguir esto y que el deslizador se pueda pulsar en cualquiera de sus puntos, no sólo en el medio. Por ejemplo, en el siguiente enlace he conseguido hacer un deslizador bien ancho pero sólo funciona bien si seleccionamos desde el punto medio.

http://codepen.io/mibastid/pen/qqVPbw?editors=1100

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con: solo funciona bien si seleccionamos desde el punto medio?

Comment: A ver, es que no se muy bien como explicarlo. Si tu tienes un input range normal, solo puedes deslizarlo desde el deslizador por defecto, en cambio en el que he compartido como ejemplo, parece que puedes deslizar desde cualquier punto de la zona roja, pero no es así, ya que selecciones donde selecciones siempre te centra el cursor en el punto medio de la zona roja. Gracias @Error404

Comment: Ahora he visto el efecto al que te refieres. Sin embargo, desconozco si se puede arrastrar simplemente de uno de los laterales, lo siento.

Comment: Me ha costado entenderlo porque solo le has dado estilos para webkit y en Firefox no lo veía bien. Yo diría que no es posible hacer eso, al menos no se me ocurre como

Comment: Al parecer el funcionamiento de este componente nativo es ubicar el centro del `deslizador` al la posición del `puntero` del `mouse`. El hecho de que en `webkit` se pueda `customizar` no implica que se pueda modificar el comportamiento, por lo que yo también diría que no es posible a no ser que crees tu propio `componente range`, el cual no use como base un `input type range`.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos. Ya siento no explicarme mejor pero no sabía como decirlo. En cuanto a que no se puede sospechaba que con el input range. Probaré a crear uno propio para ver si así consigo algo, os iré contando por aquí

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 18px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height:8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  /*Este valor es el que lo hace mas "grueso"*/
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -14px;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #367ebd;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 16px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #2a6495;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #3071a9;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #3071a9;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #367ebd;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" name="ageInputName" id="ageInputId" value="0" min="1" max="100" oninput="ageOutputId.value = ageInputId.value">
    <output name="ageOutputName" id="ageOutputId">0</output>
```

El value determina donde estará ubicado el control de range:

```html
<input type="range" name="ageInputName" id="ageInputId" value="0" min="1" max="100" oninput="ageOutputId.value = ageInputId.value">
    <output name="ageOutputName" id="ageOutputId">0</output>
```